# Azure not getting devicealreadyexists exception

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

When I am registering device in IoT Hub with a device_id which is already used, I am not getting the error  409001 devicealreadyexists. Could someone give me a clue of that might be? Thanks

Comment: Are you testing it directly in Azure Portal?

Comment: I am testing this with code. If we try to create a device directly in the Azure portal, it works fine and it tells us, that we already have device created with that id.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? It's difficult to answer this question without a reproducible example or at least some information on what SDK/language/methods you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that The device or module ID stored in the identity registry of Azure IoT Hub is case-sensitive. Make sure you are registering the same device with case-sensitive rule in mind.

Reference: [Understand the identity registry in your IoT hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry)